# Why is this apparmor audit of freedesktop happening on a server?

Tags: server, 20.04, dbus

I'm seeing the following message, every minute, on an Ubuntu 20.04 server:

> audit: type=1107 audit(1705667553.200:749917): pid=499 uid=102 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/DBus" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus" member="Hello" mask="send" name="org.freedesktop.DBus" pid=639210 label="docker-default" peer_label="unconfined"
> exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=102 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'

Not sure why the `docker-default` profile is hitting this. Also not sure how to check that.

The process with pid 499 is this:

```
/usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation --syslog-only
```

The output of this command is emtpy:

```
sudo apparmor_status | grep dbus
```

I don't see what's causing this, or how I can fix it. Can anyone help?